# Using 7Zip to make a WAR file

Tags: java, war, 7zip

I know you can take a WAR file or EAR and unzip it using 7Zip or other archiving utilities. But does this process work in reverse? Can 7Zip create a valid WAR artifact using it's GUI manager? EAR?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?  But seriously, you *should not* be assembling your JAR / WAR / EAR files by hand.  You should be using an IDE ... or better still, a scripted Java build system such as Ant or Maven.

Comment: As Stephen C mentioned, use a build system. I would prefer ANT. Take a look at [here](http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/how-to-create-a-war-file-using-ant/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `war` file is a `jar` with a special purpose and wikipedia tells us:

> They can also use zip tools to do so; however, the order of entries in the zip file headers is important when compressing, as the manifest often needs to be first.

So to my understanding, you can use 7zip from a technical perspective but you *may* have to make sure, that you add the manifest file(s) first.